# Big-commerce not fetch the product but not update

Tags: php, bigcommerce

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'client_id' => 'xxxxxx',
'auth_token' => 'xxxxx',
'store_hash' => 'xxxxxx'
));
$product = Bigcommerce::getProduct(3352);
echo $product->name;
echo $product->price;
$product->price = 28.95;
if($product->update()){
    $product = Bigcommerce::getProduct(3352);
   echo $product->name;
  echo $product->price;
}
```

I have this code we fetch the product but not updated, Please help

Comment: Does it work if you call the update() function without evaluating it as an if statement? For example: 
`$product = Bigcommerce::getProduct(3352);

$product->price = 28.95;
$product->update();`

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tried without if but no success

Comment: Any reason you are running update in an if statement? What is the end goal?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code to work.

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;


    Bigcommerce::configure(array(

        'client_id' => 'XXXXXX',
        'auth_token' => 'XXXXX',
        'store_hash' => 'XXXXX'
    ));


$product = Bigcommerce::getProduct(119);
echo $product->name;
echo $product->price;
$product->price = 12.95; 
$product->update();
echo $product->price;
?>
```